# query linq to xml

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I've this xml file. I'm trying to obtain all dbistance for a specific servername attribute.
For each dbistance information group i want add at listbox the result of concatenation 
like this  DEFAULT - DBCATALOG - USERNAME - PASSWORD - 1433
please me...beginning to hate linq :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <server servername="SRV01">
    <dbistance>
      <istancename>DEFAULT</istancename>
      <catalog>DBCATALOG01</catalog>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>PASSWORD</password>
      <port>1433</port>
    </dbistance>
    <dbistance>
      <istancename>DEFAULT</istancename>
      <catalog>DBCATALOG02</catalog>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>PASSWORD</password>
      <port>1433</port>
    </dbistance>
  </server>

  <server servername="SRV02">
    <dbistance>
      <istancename>DEFAULT</istancename>
      <catalog>DBCATALOG01</catalog>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>PASSWORD</password>
      <port>1433</port>   
    </dbistance>
  </server>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
var result = doc.Root
                .Descendants("dbistance")
                .Select(elem => elem.Descendants()
                                    .Select(elem2 => elem2.Value)
                                    .Aggregate((current, next) => current + " - " + next));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd split parsing xml and results formatting into two actions. But here is a single query:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
string serverName = "SRV01";
IEnumerable<string> dbInstances =
            xdoc.Descendants("server")
                .Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("servrname") == serverName)
                .Descendants("dbinstance")
                .Select(db => String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", 
                    (string)db.Element("istancename"),
                    (string)db.Element("catalog"),
                    (string)db.Element("username"),
                    (string)db.Element("password"),
                       (int)db.Element("port")));
```

BTW you have typo in `istancename` tag.

---

Consider also creating class which will hold data and do formatting for you:

```
public class DbInstance
{
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    public string Catalog { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }

    public override ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", 
                  InstanceName, Catalog, UserName, Password, Port));
    }
}
```

Parse xml (you can do it in separate method, which will return collection of DbInstance objects):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
string serverName = "SRV01";
IEnumerable<DbInstance> dbInstances =
            xdoc.Descendants("server")
                .Where(s => (string)s.Attribute("servrname") == serverName)
                .Descendants("dbinstance")
                .Select(db => new DbInstance() {
                    InstanceName = (string)db.Element("istancename"),
                    Catalog = (string)db.Element("catalog"),
                    UserName = (string)db.Element("username"),
                    Password = (string)db.Element("password"),
                    Port = (int)db.Element("port") });
```

And just assign instances to listbox (overridden ToString method will do the job):

```
listBox.DataSource = dbInstances;
```

Comment: I like also that your answer is guaranteed to give right order of elements, while mine depends on order of nodes.

Comment: @RomanPekar hold on, investigating your answer.. looks interesting